# Change span class title based on JSON file data

Tags: html, css, json, angular

My goal is to generate a tool tip using the title attribute of a span class, but to have the title content change depending on the span class.

Today, I have a JSON file that has an attribute of status, which is represented with status color (e.g. gray, blue, orange, etc). Example:

```
  {
    "area":"Grouping",
    "title": "Information Architecture",
    "link": "#",
    "password": "",
    "designer": "Some Name Here",
    "status": "purple",
    "dateupdated": "2019-07-18"
  },
```

Then I use angular to show this data. Here is the status column:

```
<ng-template
  let-row="row"
  let-value="value"
  #statusColumnTemplate>
  <span class="{{ value }}" title="Test title"></span>
</ng-template>
```

Obviously with this code, no matter what class color is passed in the title will be the same. Ideally, I'd like a different message in the title for each class, but I am unsure how to do this.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you share a copy in stackbiltz?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have 2 possibilities to achieve that:

1. You can write your condition directly into the `title`-tag like this:

```
<span class="{{ value }}" [title]="value === 'something' ? 'Tooltip on match' : 'Tooltip on else'">
</span>
```

2. You can write your entire spans conditionally with an `*ngIf` structural directive:

```
<span *ngIf="value === 'something'" class="{{ value }}" title="First Tooltip">
</span>
<span *ngIf="value !== 'something'" class="{{ value }}" title="Second Tooltip">
</span>
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this now. :)

Edit: This worked perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: Another possibility would be to create a `title` object in component and use it in template: `<span class="{{ value }}" title="{{ title[value] }}"></span>`

Comment: Glad I could help :)